# webpack-dev-middleware pass through for all routes

Tags: reactjs, webpack, react-router, webpack-dev-middleware

I'm using [webpack-dev-middleware](https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-middleware) along with a react app using react-router on the client.

All is well if i enter the application at the root `/`,  but `webpack-dev-middleware` will not serve anything with a path, like '/my-route`

```
server.use(webpackDevMiddleware(compiler, {
    publicPath: '/'
}));
```

I tried using a wildcard, which allows all paths to pass through and get the html page,  but then it seems when the page requests the `main.js`,  it now also gets the html page, instead of the packaged javascript.

```
server.use('/*', webpackDevMiddleware(compiler, {
    publicPath: '/'
}));
```

The goal is that any route the server doesn't know about, gets the same content as the root, and then react-router will handle showing the correct view (or 404) on the client.

any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: is that webpack dev server the _final_ middleware after you register all of your routes?

Answer (score 19):

Try [connect-history-api-fallback](https://github.com/bripkens/connect-history-api-fallback) npm package, which is what webpack-dev-server uses under the hood for the same purpose.

This worked for me:

```
var history = require('connect-history-api-fallback');
server.use(history());
server.use(webpackDevMiddleware(compiler, {
  publicPath: '/'
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue and my solution was to update react-router-config and react-router-dom packages. No further actions required.

I went from 4.x to 5.0.1 (in both packages).